# I have development SharePoint 2016 farm with 2 servers one SharePoint and one SQL server 2014, SharePoint server is lost

Tags: disaster-recovery

I have development SharePoint 2016 farm with 2 servers one SharePoint and one SQL server 2014, SharePoint server is lost and infra team cannot restore it,
I have content database can i restore it in new sharepoint farm and what the best solution for that case especially that all my progress in that server and deployed solutions and 2 portals were in progress.